# Secure IIS SMTP Server with username and password

Tags: smtp

How can I allow remote users send email via my SMTP Server (the Windows Server built-in SMTP Server) only if they know a username/password pair that I set?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838987/cannot-authenticate-to-smtp-server-with-windows-authentication
It looks like the "Basic authentication" option is what you need.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Maybe you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the "Basic Authentication" option on the Authentication dialog. Create a local account/password on the server, and then the SMTP client can provide those credentials.[image: SMTP Authentication dialog]